# strange issue when using XamlReader to load xaml with xml:space="preserve"

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, xamlreader

I found a very strange issue when to use XamlReader to load the menu of my app from a predefined xaml file.
I need to define the attribute of `xml:space="preserve"` and the xaml is like this:

```
<m:MenuManager>
   ...
    <m:Resource>
        <m:Resource.ResourceTitle>
            <sys:String xml:space="preserve">Click the Button&#xA;(InvokeCommandAction)&#xA;View</sys:String>
        </m:Resource.ResourceTitle>
    </m:Resource>
...
</m:MenuManager>
```

Load the xaml content to the string and use `XamlReader.Load` to convert it to the MenuManager object. When at the first time the `XamlReader.Load` method is called, it will only return the words within the tag `<sys:String xml:space="preserve">` , and the expected result only returned at the second time.

```
        var uri = new Uri("/Sample;component/Assets/Menu.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
        var info = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
        string xaml = null;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(info.Stream))
        {
            xaml = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        //when the first time load, only a string value of
        //"Click the Button&#xA;(InvokeCommandAction)&#xA;View" is returned
        var temp1 = XamlReader.Load(xaml); 

        //when the second time load, all menu content loaded successfully and
        //converted to the object of MenuManager 
        readXaml = XamlReader.Load(xaml) as MenuManager;
```

When I remove the attribute `xml:space="preserve"` or change it to `xml:space="default"` it will work fine and I can get the object of MenuManager by calling the method `XamlReader.Load` only once.But I really need keep the whitespace on my page, and the code here looks so strange. Can anybody please explain this?
Thanks!

Comment: also reported as a bug https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/615562/xml-space-preserve-goes-out-of-scope-when-used-twice-in-nested-elements maybe used internally ,so can be reserved a word.

Comment: yes, i upgrade the sl version from 4 to 5, and it was solved

Answer (score 1):

if you dont want to add `xml:space="preserve"` to all elements, you could use this additional parameter to `XamlReader.Load` :

```
XamlReader.Load(xaml, new ParserContext() { XmlSpace = "preserve" });
```